# как в aiogra бот добавит каптчу

Tags: python, aiogram, captcha

если новый пользователь то выдаем ему каптчу, у него есть 3 попытки если в вводит неверно то бан на час, каптча по фото чисто с цифрами

Answer (score 0):

1. Генерация каптчи
2. Поместить ее на фото
3. Отправить фото пользователю
4. Проверить совпадает ли введённое значение со значением каптчи